# React-Router params not working as expected returns param name if no value passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is how I'm assigning `routes`.

```
Routes = [
{
    path: "/Hibachi/:id?",
    component: HibachiGrill,
    title: "Hibachi",
    icon: <TableOutlined />,
    exact: true,
  },
{
    path: "/Barfloor",
    component: BarFloor,
    title: "Barfloor",
    icon: <RiDashboardFill />,
    exact: true,
  },
];
```

I'm calling the `routes` like this.

```
       <LayoutAnt className="content">
          <Switch>
            {Routes.map((route, index) => (
              <Route
                key={index}
                exact={route.exact}
                path={route.path}
                component={route.component}
              />
            ))}
          </Switch>
        </LayoutAnt>
```

My question is when I don't pass any parameter in the hibachi component I get this as result `:id`
I have tried putting a `?` but I'm still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It Works fine just see this sandbox [Simple routing with your routes](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-url-parameters-forked-s7y5u?file=/example.js).

Also as you didn't mention how you access the parameters, i suppose you didn't use he `useParams` hook, that's why you might be getting unwanted props in your component.